# How to make custum layout in zing library?

Tags: android

I am working in qr code scanner project . Now i need to create custum layout for qr code scanner is it possible using zing ? any tutorial / code about this ?

Comment: There are so many libraries available, https://android-arsenal.com/tag/81

Comment: Yes you can. in that case you have to download zing library  code and modify in side it & add as module to your project in android Studio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here try this

```
 compile 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.0.3@aar'
 compile 'com.google.zxing:core:3.2.0'


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">


<com.journeyapps.barcodescanner.CompoundBarcodeView
    android:id="@+id/barcode_scanner"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

</com.journeyapps.barcodescanner.CompoundBarcodeView>

</LinearLayout>
```

In Your Activity or Fragment

```
 @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_page_three, container, false);
    barcodeView = (CompoundBarcodeView) view.findViewById(R.id.barcode_scanner);
    barcodeView.decodeContinuous(callback);

    return view;
}
```

Callback

```
 private BarcodeCallback callback = new BarcodeCallback() {
    @Override
    public void barcodeResult(BarcodeResult result) {
    String resultString = result;
    }
```

Comment: @DineshRijal I think you have to make custom UI for Zing library if not so then change question it make confuse to other people question is different that solution.

Comment: i just want to make custom layout instead of full screen default layout